# Insert data into a view (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have the following setup:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Licenses
(
 Id    int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
 Name  varchar(100),
 RUser nvarchar(128) DEFAULT USER_NAME()
)

GO

CREATE VIEW dbo.rLicenses
AS
SELECT Name
FROM   dbo.Licenses
WHERE  RUser = USER_NAME()

GO
```

When I try to insert data using the view...

```
INSERT INTO dbo.rLicenses VALUES ('test')
```

an error arises:

```
Cannot insert the value NULL into column Id, table master.dbo.Licenses; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
```

Why doesn't the auto increment of the identity column work when trying to insert using the view and how can I fix it?

Scenario is:

**The different users of the database should only be able to work with their own rows in that table. Therefore I am trying to use the view as a kind of security by checking the username.** Is there any better solution?

Comment: Why aren;t you directly inserting into that table? I never insert to views because they have wierd quirly rules and are more of a pain than a direct insert.

Comment: The different users of the database should only be able to work with their own rows in that table. Therefore I am trying to use the view as a kind of security by checking the username. Is there any better solution?

Comment: @Keeks; your code runs fine on SQL Server 2014 and SQL Server 2016 ctp 2.3

Comment: Runs fine in SQL Server 2008 R2 as well

Comment: And it works on SQL Server 2017

Answer (score 25):

What about naming your column?

```
INSERT INTO dbo.rLicenses (name) VALUES ('test')
```

It's been years since I tried updating via a view so YMMV as HLGEM mentioned.

I would consider an ["INSTEAD OF" trigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175521.aspx) on the view to allow a simple `INSERT dbo.Licenses` (ie the table) in the trigger

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you are running afoul of this rule for updating views from Books Online:
"INSERT statements must specify values for any columns in the underlying table that do not allow null values and have no DEFAULT definitions."

Comment: Ok, since the behavior is intentional do you have any idea how I could solve my problem?

Comment: Insert directly to the underlying table

Answer (score 4):

You just need to specify which columns you're inserting directly into:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[rLicenses] ([Name]) VALUES ('test')
```

Views can be picky like that.

Answer (score 3):

Go to design for that table. Now, on the right, set the ID column as the column in question. It will now auto populate without specification.

Answer (score 1):

You have created a table with `ID` as `PRIMARY KEY`, which satisfies `UNIQUE` and `NOT NULL` constraints, so you can't make the `ID` as `NULL` by inserting name field, so `ID` should also be inserted.

The error message indicates this.

Answer (score 0):

What is your Compatibility Level set to? If it's 90, it's working as designed. See [this article](http://jagbarcelo.blogspot.com/2006/09/identity-columns-in-view-treated-as.html).

In any case, why not just insert directly into the table?

Answer (score 0):

Inserting 'test' to name will lead to inserting `NULL` values to other columns of the base table which wont be correct as Id is a `PRIMARY KEY` and it cannot have `NULL` value.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO viewname (Column name) values (value);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO dbo.rLicenses
    SELECT 'test'
```

Based on [sqlhack](https://www.sqlshack.com/create-view-sql-inserting-data-through-views-in-sql-server/) in chapter "Data modifications through views"