# how can i insert into this view mysql

Tags: mysql, database

i create view and i can't insert into this view

```
create or replace view miniltd_customer_view as 
select customerNumber as custno , customerName as custname , city
as custcity , country as custcountry from customers where customerName like '%Ltd.';
```

```
insert into miniltd_customer_view (custno , custname , custcity , custcountry) values (9000 , 'SUNISA Ltd.' , 'Texas' , 'USA');
```

result

```
underlying table doesn't have a default value
```

thanks for help

Comment: Can you share the definition of the table?

Comment: I guess you did not search for similar questions as this already been [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4197674/insert-data-into-a-view-sql-server/43191258)

Comment: this is my table CREATE TABLE `customers` (
  `customerNumber` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `customerName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `contactLastName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `contactFirstName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `country` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`customerNumber`),
  KEY `salesRepEmployeeNumber` (`salesRepEmployeeNumber`),
  CONSTRAINT `customers_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`salesRepEmployeeNumber`) REFERENCES `employees` (`employeeNumber`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your insertion has to include all `NOT NULL` fields

Possible solutions:

1. Change insertion query by adding all required fields
2. Modify table structure and allow nullable

Problematic fields:

1. `contactLastName`
2. `contactFirstName`
3. `phone`

All those fields are not null by definition and you did not provide any value on insertion.

```
CREATE TABLE customers ( 
  customerNumber int(11) NOT NULL, 
  customerName varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
  contactLastName varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
  contactFirstName varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
  phone varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
  salesRepEmployeeNumber int(11),
  city varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
  country varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY (customerNumber), 
  KEY salesRepEmployeeNumber (salesRepEmployeeNumber), 
  CONSTRAINT customers_ibfk_1 
  FOREIGN KEY (salesRepEmployeeNumber) 
  REFERENCES employees (employeeNumber) 
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

create or replace view miniltd_customer_view as 
select customerNumber as custno , 
customerName as custname , 
city as custcity , 
country as custcountry 
from customers where customerName like '%Ltd.';

insert into miniltd_customer_view (custno , custname , custcity , custcountry) values (9000 , 'SUNISA Ltd.' , 'Texas' , 'USA');
```

Live example

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a42221

Answer (score 0):

Views should be used to retrieve data. I recommend inserting into the table.

Try modifying your statement to insert into the table as shown below:

```sql
insert into customers (customerNumber , customerName , city , country) values (9000 , 'SUNISA Ltd.' , 'Texas' , 'USA');
```

However based on your schema definition

```sql
CREATE TABLE customers ( 
    customerNumber int(11) NOT NULL, 
    customerName varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
    contactLastName varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
    contactFirstName varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
    phone varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
    city varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
    country varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (customerNumber), 
    KEY salesRepEmployeeNumber (salesRepEmployeeNumber), 
   CONSTRAINT customers_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (salesRepEmployeeNumber) REFERENCES employees (employeeNumber) 
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

you are missing required values for  `contactLastName,contactFirstName,phone` in your insert statement which your view also does not reference. This raises the error that there are no default values for these fields when there are defined in your table schema as `NON NULL`.

A more complete insert statement would look like:

```sql
insert into customers (customerNumber , customerName , contactLastName, contactFirstName, phone, city , country) values (9000 , 'SUNISA Ltd.' ,'First Name N/A','Last Name N/A', 'Phone N/A', 'Texas' , 'USA');
```

You may also modify your table schema to accommodate default values and try to insert as you are doing now. A complete example with demo fiddle

```
CREATE TABLE customers ( 
    customerNumber int(11) NOT NULL, 
    customerName varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
    contactLastName varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
    contactFirstName varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
    phone varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
    city varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
    country varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (customerNumber)
  
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

insert into customers (customerNumber , customerName , contactLastName, contactFirstName, phone, city , country) values (9000 , 'Test Ltd.' ,'Bob','Brown', '333-444-5555', 'Texas' , 'USA');

alter table customers modify contactLastName varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Last Name N/A';

alter table customers modify contactFirstName varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'First Name N/A';

alter table customers modify phone varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Phone N/A';


insert into customers (customerNumber , customerName ,  city , country) values (9001 , 'SUNISA Ltd.' , 'Texas' , 'USA');

create or replace view miniltd_customer_view as 
select customerNumber as custno , 
customerName as custname , 
city as custcity , 
country as custcountry 
from customers where customerName like '%Ltd.';

insert into miniltd_customer_view (custno , custname , custcity , custcountry) values (9002 , 'SUNISA2 Ltd.' , 'Texas' , 'USA');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
select * from customers;
```

| customerNumber | customerName | contactLastName | contactFirstName | phone | city | country |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9000 | Test Ltd. | Bob | Brown | 333-444-5555 | Texas | USA |
| 9001 | SUNISA Ltd. | Last Name N/A | First Name N/A | Phone N/A | Texas | USA |
| 9002 | SUNISA2 Ltd. | Last Name N/A | First Name N/A | Phone N/A | Texas | USA |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9RvTy6cAvLGdowYjMv3yk4/0)

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Why did you add default values? its garbage information

Comment: The OP can decide what they would like to use as default values. I only presented different approaches to the resolution which the OP must decide which one is best for them based on their business requirements.